# Accessing %appdata% with c

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I want to make a program that open a text file present in the **startup** folder.Write something to it and close it. Can i use **%APPDATA%** in my path because user name is changed at every pc I used as below but its not working.

```
FILE *fptr
fptr = fopen("%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\myfile.txt","w");
```

Comment: As an aside, you should not be putting data files in the "Startup" folder. It's for shortcuts to launch programs on startup.

Comment: @AndrewMedico but it allows to copy paste data files in it manually then why not with a program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular way to get environment variables is to use [`getenv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx)

```
char * appdata = getenv("APPDATA");
if (!appdata) { /* error */ }
char buffer[0x400];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)
    , "%s\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\myfile.txt", appdata);
fptr = fopen(buffer,"w");
```

Please keep in mind that in windows environment variables are **not** case sensitive.

Comment: Its giving linker error 
**undefined symbol in module myprogram.c**

Comment: Does the linker tell you which symbol is undefined ?

Comment: I suppose you are using a Visual Studio. Replacing `snprintf` by `_snprintf` shoud do the job.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes it tells **_snprintf**

Comment: @MichaelWalz iam using turbo c

Comment: @MichaelWalz it is now showing **two underscores** before **snprintf**

Comment: no it again shos error with two underscores with sprintf like this "Linker error undefined symbol**__snprintf** in module"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50797/discussion-between-user3536228-and-michael-walz)